# How to structure angular code

Tags: angular

I am building my site with angular5. I guess for now my site is not so complicated. But I am not sure what is the proper/conventional way to organize my code.

So I have a nav bar with associated components(after hitting the buttons it will direct to component html). Say component A B C D. So:

1. Where do I write my index-page code? Do I write it in index.html, app.component.html or shall I create a new component called "home"?
2. Moreover, what is app.component.html used for? Is it only used for common part of the application or is it used for homepage?

(I guess more or less it is the same question)

Comment: Have you taken a loot at Angular.io best practices? This is also a good resource: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure

Answer (score 0):

If you weren't impressed with the best practices suggested on Angular.io. Take a peek at this, it's pretty straight forward and should give you a good idea of a structure that generally will scale pretty well:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure

Answer (score 0):

Try going for @angular/cli which gives you well organized structured boilerplate code.

> Where do I write my index-page code? Do I write it in index.html,
>   app.component.html or shall I create a new component called "home"?

Its best to create a separate folder for each component inside which you can put your html, component, styles etc. Maybe you can club all the layout / nav related components and put them under a /layout directoy which hold all your base layouts used throughout the app.

> Moreover, what is app.component.html used for? Is it only used for
>   common part of the application or is it used for homepage?

app.component.html will hold your router-outlet, selectors for other components that you might want to add, which again depends on you design and layout. It is mapped with your AppComponent which is like the first component that your app is loading inside again you will have series of nested components.